# How to convert streaming Dataset to DStream?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Is it possible to convert a streaming `o.a.s.sql.Dataset` to `DStream`? If so, how?

I know how to convert it to RDD, but it is in a streaming context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible. Structured Streaming and legacy Spark Streaming (`DStreams`) use completely different semantics and are not compatible with each other so:

- `DStream` cannot be converted to Streaming `Dataset`.
- Streaming `Dataset` cannot be converted to `DStream`.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible (in some use cases).

That question really begs another:

> Why would anyone want to do that conversion? What's the problem to be solved?

I can only imagine that such **type** conversion would only be required when mixing two different APIs in a single streaming application. I'd then say it does not make much sense as you'd rather not do this and make the conversion at Spark module level, i.e. migrate the streaming application from Spark Streaming to Spark Structured Streaming.

A streaming `Dataset` is an "abstraction" of a series of `Datasets` (I use quotes since the difference between streaming and batch `Dataset`s is the `isStreaming` property of a `Dataset`).

It is possible to convert a `DStream` to a streaming `Dataset` so the latter behaves as the former (to keep the behaviour of the `DStream` and pretend to be a streaming `Dataset`).

Under the covers, the execution engines of Spark Streaming (`DStream`) and Spark Structured Streaming (streaming `Dataset`) are fairly similar. They both "generate" micro-batches of RDDs and Datasets, respectively. And RDDs are convertible to Datasets but this implicit conversion `toDF` or `toDS`.

So converting a `DStream` to a streaming `Dataset` would logically look as follows:

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  val df = rdd.toDF
  // this df is not streaming, but you don't really need that
}
```