# How to use writeStream to pass Spark stream to a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am using twitter stream function which gives a stream. I am required to use Spark writeStream function like:[writeStream function link](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#creating-a-kafka-sink-for-streaming-queries)

```
// Write key-value data from a DataFrame to a specific Kafka topic specified in an option
val ds = df
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic1")
  .start()
```

The 'df' needs to be a streaming Dataset/DataFrame. If df is a normal DataFrame, it will give error showing 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;

I have already done:
1. get stream from twitter
2. filter and map it to get a tag for each twitt (Positive, Negative, Natural)

The last step is to groupBy tag and count for each and pass it to Kafka.

Do you guys have any idea how to transform a Dstream into a streaming Dataset/DataFrame?

> Edited: ForeachRDD function does change Dstream to normal DataFrame.
>   But 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming
>   Dataset/DataFrame. (writeStream link is provided above)
>
> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert RDD to DataFrame in Spark Streaming, not just Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996549/how-to-convert-rdd-to-dataframe-in-spark-streaming-not-just-spark)

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for your info. I did it before. I update the question to be more specific.

Comment: Ah, apparently it is not possible... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49559007/convert-between-streaming-dataset-and-dstream But you can write batches instead https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka

Comment: What's _"twitter stream function"_? Can you show the code that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to transform a Dstream into a streaming Dataset/DataFrame?

`DStream` is an abstraction of a series of RDDs.

A streaming `Dataset` is an "abstraction" of a series of `Dataset`s (I use quotes since the difference between streaming and batch `Dataset`s is a property `isStreaming` of `Dataset`).

It is possible to convert a `DStream` to a streaming `Dataset` to keep the behaviour of the `DStream`.

I think you don't really want it though.

All you need is to take tweets using `DStream` and save them to a Kafka topic (and you think you need Structured Streaming). I think you simply need Spark SQL (the underlying engine of Structured Streaming).

A pseudo-code would then be as follows (sorry it's been a longer while since I used the old-fashioned Spark Streaming):

```
val spark: SparkSession = ...
val tweets = DStream...
tweets.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  import spark.implicits._
  rdd.toDF.write.format("kafka")...
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it gives me error. Finally, I use KafkaProducer to write message to my topic.

Comment: @DDJin What's the error? Let me help you if you don't mind :)